# TokenURI Stack too Deep Errors

Tags: solidity, erc-721

I am trying a slightly different approach to the TokenURI with dynamic metadata in my ERC721 NFT.
As the metadata can change I generate the TokenURI in the contract as required, it works fine but I am now hitting a limit of the stack depth. This is the code I have but it is giving me the stack depth error.

```
contract TokenURIMaker {

    constructor() {}

    function baseSection(string calldata name, string calldata description, string calldata image, string calldata annimation)internal pure returns(bytes memory) {
        bytes memory base = abi.encodePacked('{"name": "',
            name,
            '", "image": "',
            image,
            '", "description": "',
            description,
            '","animation_url": "',
            annimation);

            return base;
    }
    function atributesSection(string calldata avatarWL, uint wlSpots, uint winChances, uint softClay )internal pure returns(bytes memory){
        bytes memory atri = abi.encodePacked('", "attributes": [{ "trait_type": "Avatar WL", "value": "',
            avatarWL,
            '"},{ "display_type": "boost_number","trait_type": "City WL Spots", "value": "',
             Strings.toString(wlSpots),
            '"},{ "display_type": "boost_number","trait_type": "Win Chances", "value": "',
             Strings.toString(winChances),
            '"},{ "display_type": "boost_number","trait_type": "Soft Clay", "value": "',
             Strings.toString(softClay),
            '"}]}');
            return atri;
    }

    function maketokenURi(string calldata name, string calldata image, string calldata description, string calldata annimation, string calldata avatarWL, uint wlSpots, uint winChances, uint softClay ) external pure returns(string memory){
        
        bytes memory base = baseSection(name, description, image, annimation);
        bytes memory atri = atributesSection(avatarWL, wlSpots, winChances, softClay);
        bytes memory dataURI = abi.encodePacked(
            base, atri
        );
        return
            string(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    "data:application/json;base64,",
                    Base64.encode(dataURI)
                )
            );
    }

}
```

This code works but it doesn't have all the metadata I want to show.

```
function maketokenURi(string calldata name, string calldata image, string calldata description, string calldata annimation, string calldata avatarWL, uint wlSpots, uint winChances, uint softClay ) external pure returns(string memory){
        
       bytes memory dataURI = abi.encodePacked(
            '{"name": "',
            name,
            '", "image": "',
            image,
            
            '","animation_url": "',
            annimation,
            '", "attributes": [{ "trait_type": "Avatar WL", "value": "',
            avatarWL,
            '"},{ "display_type": "boost_number","trait_type": "City WL Spots", "value": "',
             Strings.toString(wlSpots),
            '"},{ "display_type": "boost_number","trait_type": "Win Chances", "value": "',
             Strings.toString(winChances),
            '"},{ "display_type": "boost_number","trait_type": "Soft Clay", "value": "',
             Strings.toString(softClay),
            '"}]}'
        );
        return
            string(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    "data:application/json;base64,",
                    Base64.encode(dataURI)
                )
            );
    }
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Function parameters add variables to the stack. This also goes for 'abi.encode' I believe. You should be able to split it up like this.

```
    function maketokenURi(
        string calldata name,
        string calldata image,
        string calldata description,
        string calldata annimation,
        string calldata avatarWL,
        uint256 wlSpots,
        uint256 winChances,
        uint256 softClay
    ) external pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory attributes = abi.encodePacked(
            '[{ "trait_type": "Avatar WL", "value": "',
            avatarWL,
            '"},{ "display_type": "boost_number","trait_type": "City WL Spots", "value": "',
            Strings.toString(wlSpots),
            '"},{ "display_type": "boost_number","trait_type": "Win Chances", "value": "',
            Strings.toString(winChances),
            '"},{ "display_type": "boost_number","trait_type": "Soft Clay", "value": "',
            Strings.toString(softClay),
            '"}]'
        );

        bytes memory dataURI = abi.encodePacked(
            '{"name": "',
            name,
            '", "image": "',
            image,
            '","animation_url": "',
            annimation,
            '","attributes": ',
            attributes,
            '}'
        );

        return string(abi.encodePacked("data:application/json;base64,", Base64.encode(dataURI)));
    }
```

Other ways would be to call another intermediate function that returns a partial string of the json.

PS: Bonus points if using 0.8.13 's `string memory result = string.concat(a, b)` method. More bonus points for removing typos and adhering to naming conventions ("makeTokenURI", "animation")

Edit: I might've misread that it's actually the top code that you're struggling with.

Here another possible remedy by using structs for your data:

```
contract TokenURIMaker {
    constructor() {}

    struct JsonData {
        string name;
        string image;
        string description;
        string annimation;
        string avatarWL;
        uint256 wlSpots;
        uint256 winChances;
        uint256 softClay;
    }

    function baseSection(JsonData calldata json) internal pure returns (bytes memory) {
        bytes memory base = abi.encodePacked(
            '{"name": "',
            json.name,
            '", "image": "',
            json.image,
            '", "description": "',
            json.description,
            '","animation_url": "',
            json.annimation
        );

        return base;
    }

    function atributesSection(JsonData calldata json) internal pure returns (bytes memory) {
        bytes memory atri = abi.encodePacked(
            '", "attributes": [{ "trait_type": "Avatar WL", "value": "',
            json.avatarWL,
            '"},{ "display_type": "boost_number","trait_type": "City WL Spots", "value": "',
            Strings.toString(json.wlSpots),
            '"},{ "display_type": "boost_number","trait_type": "Win Chances", "value": "',
            Strings.toString(json.winChances),
            '"},{ "display_type": "boost_number","trait_type": "Soft Clay", "value": "',
            Strings.toString(json.softClay),
            '"}]}'
        );
        return atri;
    }

    function maketokenURi(JsonData calldata json) external pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory base = baseSection(json);
        bytes memory atri = atributesSection(json);
        bytes memory dataURI = abi.encodePacked(base, atri);
        return string(abi.encodePacked("data:application/json;base64,", Base64.encode(dataURI)));
    }
}
```